# How to hide div on swipe in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

*What do I want to do?*

I want to close / hide a div when swiped right.

*What does the div do?*

It is a pop-up that is being shown when I click some button. I want to close this pop-up (this div) when I swipe to the right.

*What do I use?*

Ionic.

In my **app.js**, I have this:

```
    $scope.warn = function (message) {
      alert(message);
    };
```

And in the HTML file where the div is, I have this:

```
<div on-swipe-right="warn('Must use scope')">....</div>
```

It gives me an alert, so I know the swipe gesture works.

Now, I want to hide the div when I swipe to the right, but I don't know how to implement this with `ng-show`. Or should I use **CSS**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. Just keep track of a 'showing' flag, something like this:

```
<div on-swipe-right="close(message)"
     ng-hide="hide">....</div>
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.close = function (message) {
    $scope.hide = true;
};
```

---

Seeing that you use terms as 'message', you probably use an `ng-repeat`. In that case, you can do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages">
    <div on-swipe-right="close(message)"
         ng-hide="message.closed">....</div>
</div>
```

And your controller:

```
$scope.messages = [{
    text:"someText"
}, {
    text:"some other text"
}];

$scope.close = function (message) {
    message.closed = true;
};
```